# I have a couple editors and a couple terminals. Can I pair them so a terminal IDs with a file in the editor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal, editor, settings

I have a terminal that is specific to my main file. Next to that file, I have another file. I am hoping to have its terminal automatically open when I switch from the main file to the secondary file. Since they do not share the same file folder, I don't want to use the same terminal. I'm new to this, thank you.[It won't let me attach an image yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZLWS.png)

Comment: Hi, can you please be more informative. Terminal where? In your vscode IDE? Can you add a screenshot if that can help us get more idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have two instances of a terminal, can one terminal be assigned to your first file in your editor and the other assigned to the second file in your editor? It would be convenient if the second terminal popped up when the second file is selected...